# Google Apps + HTML + Regexp fetch all links anchors

Tags: regex, xml-parsing, google-apps-script, html-parsing

Summary:
how to write regexp for Google App Script that will fwtch all anchors of links from html

My Task: 
I have GoogleSpreadsheet with URLs where links to my website are (webmaster->links to me -> export).
I need anchors crawler (using google app script) to see whick links are spammed.

Realisation (what I can do):

```
function doGetLinks(url, link, encoding) 
{
  var encoding = "windows-1251";
  Utilities.sleep(1000);

  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(encoding); 
  var matched = page.match(/<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href\s*=\s*(\"([^"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'">\s]+)).*<\/a>/gim);

  var amt = "$0";
  if (matched != null)
  {

    for (var i in matched) 
    {
      var anchor = matched[i];        
      amt = anchor + " | ";     
   }        

  }

  return amt;
}
```

how to see it:

- write any cell formula =doGetLinks("http://4uarticles.net/15295/insulating-oil-reconditioning/", "articlesynergy.com")

Problems (what I can't):

1. how to write regexp for to returns anchors only
2. how to force it to return all matching links (now only first is returned, althoug key
   /g is used)
3. how to inbuild variable 'link' in regexp -- it has no
   quotes to do it. but i need to see links only to my website

Comment: you can see sample https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ap5D58-gT2y7dC1IN1JtTUpzcG5PeElvQnM3SzFWUHc&usp=docslist_api#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

While you might be able to hardcode some scenarios, you wont cover the general case. If you dont believe me ask this guy: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Good recommendation.

But it also suggest that framework shoud have powerfool html parsing tool.




I tried --
    var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var doc = XmlService.parse(html);
    var html = doc.getRootElement();
it returns error for invalid xhtml that is used on real pages

Also I tried:
    var doc = Xml.parse(page, true);
    var body = doc.html.body;
    var a = body.getElements("a");
    a = a.getText();
    return a;
It returns no erros, but still do not work for me
that is why I tried with Regexp -- that at least work

Comment: Html is not valid xml in general.